# Xref-find-definitions 'no definitions found' for emacs source

Tags: xref, etags

I downloaded emacs source code from http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/emacs/, and the relevant tags from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/refs/tags . I ran ctags via `ctags -e -R .` over both directories, then added the tag to my `tags-table-list`.

My tags table list value:`("/home/eli/.emacs.d/library/TAGS")`

Xref-find-definitions is still unable to find any definitions for emacs source functions or variables.

Comment: Try executing `M-x visit-tags-table` and chose a path to the TAGS file, does it change anything?

Comment: To add to the previous response, `tags-table-list` is supposed to be a list of file names (absolute ones), not directories. But anyway, try `M-x visit-tags-table` first. I hope you already generated one, or know how to do that.

Comment: @Hi-Angel No it doesn't. I've updated the question also

Comment: @Dmitry `tags-table-list` documentation states "An element that is a directory means the file "TAGS" in that directory."

Comment: Well, okay, so, I just tried putting `(python-mode)` to my `*scratch*` buffer, and executing `M-x xref-find-definitions` over it. It sends me to its declaration in `/usr/share/…` even though I have not loaded any TAGS files. With that said, it would be great if you provided a step-by-step minimal reproducible example of what you're doing, so we wouldn't have to guess. As a side note, you don't have to modify any variables for tags-based navigation to work, mere `M-x visit-tags-table` should be enough.

Comment: @EliRusk btw, here's a minimal example that works for me. Please enter the directory with Emacs sources inside terminal, then execute this code and see if it brings you to the source of the `print` function: `emacs -Q --eval "(progn (visit-tags-table \"./TAGS\") (xref-find-definitions \"print\"))"`. You might want to change the path to TAGS if it's in a different place, I'm just assuming it's in the same directory where sources are.

Comment: Ah, actually nvm, my example don't necessarily should work, it probably brings me because the location of `print` function is inside the Emacs build I have, not in the TAGS file.

Comment: So, I posted an answer, hopefully I figured out your problem. But I also want to point out that tags-based navigation is often overly coarse. It helps getting *some* navigation working quickly, but it won't unroll c-macros for you and won't get local function variables. For C I recommend an lsp-server such as `clangd`, that can be used in combination with tags. E.g. I do that at work, so [my Emacs consults lsp-server first, and xref stuff second](https://github.com/Hi-Angel/dotfiles/blob/b7db4b9e28dab1dbb4624c617f17e71a1b62aeb1/.emacs.d/lisp/emvil.el#L9-L12).

Answer (score 1):

If you open `TAGS` file you may find out that all paths it has are relative. And `xref-find-definitions` also works under the same assumption, i.e. that to know whether to check a `TAGS` file it first goes to check if current directory is a child of the one where the `TAGS` file is located.

In simpler terms: `xref-find-definitions` checks what project you are trying to navigate, to figure out what `TAGS` file to use for navigation.

So the bottom line is: for `xref-find-definitions` to work with tags-based navigation you need to make sure the following points hold:

1. `TAGS` file is located at the root of the repository you are trying to navigate
2. In Emacs you have focused a buffer referring to some file inside the repository you are trying to navigate

So, since you're trying to navigate Emacs project, test this: α) execute <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>visit-tags-table</kbd> and chose the `TAGS` file *(located at the root of the project!)* β) open a random file in the project, e.g. `Makefile` γ) put a caret before empty space *(to suppress autocompletion for the next command)* and execute <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>xref-find-definitions</kbd> and type in `malloc_initialize_hook`. It should send you to its location.